# Live Linux distro for text-only mode

Tags: linux, boot, software-rec, livecd

I'm looking for a Linux distro where I can boot into it via USB, run a script on startup and shutdown. I need the bare minimum, but I also need network drivers. Also I need to save files across reboots.

I've looked into Damn Small Linux with networking. Are there any other options? Fastest boot is preferred. I don't need mouse, sound, etc. Bare minimum for fast booting. To save files across reboots, should I create a USB with two partitions and save to the non OS partition? Would I have to mount this partition in the OS?

Comment: You can have a look into [TinyCore](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/welcome.html), it's just 8MiB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Debian Live Project](http://live.debian.net/) has a number of pre-built images for use as live-CDs or USB sticks, and documentation for creating your own custom live build based on Debian if you want something very specific or need something smaller/faster (the smallest standard image is ~240Mb, though boot times are not long).

The standard ones can boot to either console or X, and have pretty much the same hardware support as the main distro, and I believe they all support persistence with the right media (though I've not used persistence myself).